# Chrome extension's background page stopped logging, can't manually access any variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I want to check local storage, I run the code below in the background page's console and it usually logs everything there is.

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(result){console.log(result)})
```

However, just yesterday it started returning undefined.

I added a `console.log("running");` as the first thing in my BG page. However, when I reload the extension, nothing gets logged.

I know the data is in there because my extension continues to function properly but I cannot manually access anything + BG page doesn't log anything etc.

Even when I go to the dev tools in the BG page and check application / storage there's nothing.

Reloading the extension didn't work (there are no errors), restarting Chrome didn't work, removing the extension and adding it again didn't work, restarting my PC didn't work.

The only thing I see in the upper right hand corner of the background page is this little mention of '5 hidden' which increases when I add another console.log at the beginning of my script. It almost looks like it hides the logs? Even if so, why would the 'chrome.storage.local.get' code above return undefined?

Anybody's got an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You need to specify a key as the first parameter.

Comment: 1) Without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) we can only guess and that's not the right way to solve problems. 2) You need to unhide those messages in console: either read devtools documentation or simply reset devtools in its settings (bottom right corner).

Comment: @wOxxOm well lol, I can safely say that TIL. After the devtools reset, everything is back to normal! Thank you, as always!

Comment: My advice is to check if there's any errors see https://github.com/tomshaw/linkmate/blob/master/src/library/storage.js, Also double check if storage is enabled in the permissions of your manifest.

Comment: It was not about storage @TomShaw. Storage was working this whole time. It was about the console hiding logs, which I don't know how that came to be. Thanks for responding, though.

Comment: FWIW that library isn't even necessary because webextension-polyfill already does exactly the same internally (well, except wrapping in Error which isn't actually needed when working with the Promise API).